# Plotly Scattermapbox lines not showing but no error message

Tags: plotly, mapbox, plotly-python

I've written the following code that maps straight lines with a start and end latitude and longitude. While the code runs without an error message, the figure generated does not show any of the lines despite showing the legend.

```
fig = go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name=g[0],
            lat=np.array(g[1][["lat.start", "lat.end"]]),
            lon=np.array(g[1][["lon.start", "lon.end"]]),
            mode="lines",
        )
        for g in df.groupby("attribute")
    ]
)
```

I've looked through the documentation of Scattermapbox, but nothing suggests that `lat` and `lon` cannot take arrays, so I'm not sure why they are not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of plotting a 2D array, a 1D array can be passed instead:

```
lat=np.ravel(np.array(g[1][["lat.start", "lat.end"]])),
lon=np.ravel(np.array(g[1][["lon.start", "lon.end"]])),
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was already solved, but I created a line graph on mapbox using a data frame. The basic structure is achieved by looping through the latitude and longitude in each line of the dataframe. plotly will prepare you for the question as an example of visualization with maps.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

df_flight_paths = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_aa_flight_paths.csv')
jfk = df_flight_paths[df_flight_paths['airport1'] == 'JFK']
jfk.reset_index(inplace=True)

jfk
    index   start_lat   start_lon   end_lat     end_lon     airline     airport1    airport2    cnt
0   63  40.639751   -73.778926  26.072583   -80.152750  AA  JFK     FLL     112
1   85  40.639751   -73.778926  36.080361   -115.152333     AA  JFK     LAS     112
2   92  40.639751   -73.778926  33.942536   -118.408074     AA  JFK     LAX     548
3   128     40.639751   -73.778926  41.979595   -87.904464  AA  JFK     ORD     56
4   155     40.639751   -73.778926  32.733556   -117.189657     AA  JFK     SAN     56
5   163     40.639751   -73.778926  18.439417   -66.001833  AA  JFK     SJU     168

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(jfk)):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattermapbox(
            mode='lines',
            lat=[jfk['start_lat'][i], jfk['end_lat'][i]],
            lon=[jfk['start_lon'][i], jfk['end_lon'][i]],
            line=dict(width=jfk['cnt'][i]/50, color='red'),
            name=jfk['airport2'][i]
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    title='From jfk airport to airports',
    margin ={'l':0,'t':0,'b':0,'r':0},
    mapbox = {
        'accesstoken': token,
        'center': {'lon': -90.00, 'lat': 40.639},
        'style': 'open-street-map',
        'zoom': 4})

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is customized from [this example](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/#lines-on-maps-with-plotlygraphobjects) in the official reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was what I did initially, but my dataset is so big that running a for loop 5000 times significantly slowed plotly, so I decided to pass an array of lat lon instead. But I appreciate your insight on this

Comment: I think it's the right choice if you have such a reason. I will not delete this example and leave it as it is because I think it will help someone.